# When do files in the Android getCacheDir() get deleted? What is a better option for long term storage?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-image, android-file

I'm using the following code to save and retrieve image files (JPG) on Android:

```
File cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
```

When do these files get deleted? From what I have read this dir is not reliable as the device can delete them at any time to make space for other things. What is a better option for local storage of image files needed for my app? I'd like to rely on a permanent storage, not an SD removable card if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the app bundle space to keep your files.. I do that in my apps using:
[openFileOutput()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)
You can see there that there is also `openFileInput()` to read your files, to keep the files private, make sure you use `MODE_PRIVATE` flag with the `openFileOutput()` method.
Good luck!